# Merge [riotjs] and [riot.js]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

These tags should be merged or synonymised.

- [riotjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/riotjs) - 78 questions
- [riot.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/riot.js) - 159 questions

They both refer to the same Javascript library. [riot.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/riot.js) also has wiki.

Comment: The fastest completion I've ever seen :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, this makes sense. 28 out of the 78 questions tagged [riotjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/riotjs) also had the [riot.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/riot.js) tag. I added [riotjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/riotjs) as a synonym for [riot.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/riot.js), as the official name seems to be [Riot.JS](https://riot.js.org/):

[riotjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/riotjs) (x 78) → [riot.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/riot.js) (× 159)

These kind of tags should no longer be possible to create, as the only difference is a `.`. That said, there's also the [riot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/riot) tag, which is related to a Ruby framework, which probably needs to be renamed to something more specific to that particular framework.